# How to Handle Interdependent Component Imports in a CMake Package Config File?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a CMake based library that consists of one main CMakeLists.txt and several child CMakeLists.txt files, such that ultimately each child project defines one static library target, wtih the main project having no targets of its own and just being used to make everything work together.

The approach is such that one component consists of one target by the same name. The idea is that the library consists of several components, with the use of each being selectable by the user via the relevant option in the find_packages() command; however, naturally some of these components depend on each other (of course not circularly), which is where I've run into trouble.

For linking, the target for each component is set to depend on other components where necessary via:

```
target_link_libraries(Comp3 PUBLIC Comp1 Comp2)
```

then, regardless of dependencies, I install the targets and generate their importable *Targets.cmake files via:

```
# Install component lib
install(TARGETS Comp3
    EXPORT Comp3Targets
    COMPONENT Comp3
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
)

# Install public headers
...

# Export component targets
install(EXPORT Comp3Targets
    FILE "MyLibComp3Targets.cmake"
    NAMESPACE MyLib::
    DESTINATION cmake/Comp3
)
```

This (and obviously more) results in the following structure:

```
MyLib
  include...
  lib...
  cmake
      MyLibConfig.cmake
      MyLibConfigVersion.cmake
      Comp1
          MyLibComp1Targets.cmake
          MyLibComp1Targets-debug.cmake
          MyLibComp1Targets-release.cmake
      Comp2
          MyLibComp2Targets.cmake
          MyLibComp2Targets-debug.cmake
          MyLibComp2Targets-release.cmake
      ...
```

Where MyLibConfig.cmake was created manually with the following contents:

```
file(GLOB __MYLIB_AVAILABLE_COMPONENT_TARGETS
    RELATIVE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/*/MyLib*Targets.cmake"
)

# Components were requested
if(MyLib_FIND_COMPONENTS)
    # Check for and add each request
    foreach(component ${MyLib_FIND_COMPONENTS})
        set(component_target ${component}/MyLib${component}Targets.cmake)

        if (";${__MYLIB_AVAILABLE_COMPONENT_TARGETS};" MATCHES ";${component_target};")
            include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/${component_target}")
        elseif(MyLib_FIND_REQUIRED_${component}})
            set(MyLib_FOUND False)
            set(MyLib_NOT_FOUND_MESSAGE "Unsupported component: ${component}")
        endif()
    endforeach()
else() # Components were not requested
    # Add all components
    foreach(component_target ${__MYLIB_AVAILABLE_COMPONENT_TARGETS})
        include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/${component_target}")
    endforeach()
endif()
```

The issue is that while the way I handled component interdependencies with the target link rules works fine for building the project and linking between the libraries once they're imported, it does nothing in terms of actually making sure a target's dependencies are imported.

So basically, in this example I'd like a user of the package to be able to do:

```
find_package(MyLib REQUIRED Comp3)
```

and have the MyLibComp1Targets.cmake and MyLibComp2Targets.cmake files automatically included so the user doesn't need to care about Comp3's dependencies within the same package. But as of right now that obviously doesn't happen, and instead one needs to manually specify the dependencies as required (also in the correct order!):

```
find_package(MyLib REQUIRED Comp1 Comp2 Comp3)
```

Otherwise the generated targets export config file for Comp3 sets MyLib_FOUND to FALSE because at the time that file is processed Comp1 and Comp2 haven't been imported yet.

In theory the information is already there when I configure each component's target in my project, as in my case the dependent components match 1-to-1 with the entries in `target_link_libraries()` for each component (excluding any potential external dependencies)...

So, is there any idiomatic way to do this with built-in CMake features so that a component automatically imports the target config files that it depends on?

Or am I expected to implement the logic for this from scratch when generating my main Config.cmake file? Determining the overall import order with just CMake's functionality could certainly get messy with a decent number of components and interdependencies, and sounds like something I'd want to do in C++ itself!

Comment: You are expected to implement logic of components dependencies manually. Note, that if you have `target_link_libraries(Comp3 PUBLIC Comp1 Comp2)` then CMake won't allow you to create an EXPORT set to contain Comp3 library without Comp1 and Comp2.

Comment: Ah, that bites but I did expect it given that Components don't have any strict rules associated with them and they're more of a "do what you will with them" kind of thing. As for your note, I think I'm misunderstanding it, because I take that to mean that if I used that link statement you highlighted that I wouldn't be allowed to do `install(TARGETS Comp3 EXPORT Comp3Set` since its missing Comp1 and Comp2, and instead would need `install(TARGETS Comp1 Comp2 Comp3 EXPORT Comp3Set`); however, I'm using the former statement (as shown above too) and CMake allows the build to go through.

Answer (score 1):

While there are certainly more ways, the following is how I handled this (it wasn't too bad).

To start, note that many of the files in my output package are generated using a a healthy amount of `configure_file(... @ONLY)`, so this example is missing some finer details and is fairly abstracted.

1. Somewhere in the scripts for a given component, define a variable that contains a list of the other components in your project that the component depends on.
2. Use configure_file() to generate a CMake configuration file for each component that makes use of the variable (and more) in 1.

Example Output For One Component (MyLibComp3Config.cmake):

```
# Guard against multiple imports
if(NOT DEFINED __MYLIB_COMP3)
    message(STATUS "[MyLib] Importing component: Comp3...")
    set(__MYLIB_COMP3 TRUE)

    # Inter-component dependencies (inserted when this file was configured)
    set(__MYLIB_COMP3_SIBLING_DEPENDS Comp1 Comp2)

    # Import above dependencies first
    foreach(sibling ${__MYLIB_COMP3_SIBLING_DEPENDS})
        message(STATUS "[MyLib] Component Comp3 depends on ${sibling}")
        include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../${sibling}/MyLib${sibling}Config.cmake")
    endforeach()

    # Import component targets
    message(STATUS "[MyLib] Importing Comp3 targets...")
    include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/MyLibComp3Targets.cmake")
else()
    message(STATUS "[MyLib] Skipping already imported component: Comp3")
endif()
```

3. Tweak the original main configuration file to include these new component config files instead of their targets directly.

MyLibConfig.cmake:

```
file(GLOB __MYLIB_AVAILABLE_COMPONENTS
    RELATIVE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/*/MyLib*Config.cmake"
)

# Components were requested
if(MyLib_FIND_COMPONENTS)

    # Check for and add each request
    foreach(req_component ${MyLib_FIND_COMPONENTS})
        set(req_component_config ${req_component}/MyLib${req_component}Config.cmake)

        if (";${__MYLIB_AVAILABLE_COMPONENTS};" MATCHES ";${req_component_config};")
            include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/${req_component_config}")
        elseif(MyLib_FIND_REQUIRED_${req_component}})
            set(MyLib_FOUND False)
            set(MyLib_NOT_FOUND_MESSAGE "Unsupported component: ${req_component}")
        endif()
    endforeach()
else() # Components were not requested
    # Add all components
    foreach(component_config ${__MYLIB_AVAILABLE_COMPONENTS})
        include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/${component_config}")
    endforeach()
endif()
```

Overall the output package structure will now look like:

```
MyLib
  include...
  lib...
  cmake
      MyLibConfig.cmake
      MyLibConfigVersion.cmake
      Comp1
          MyLibComp1Config.cmake
          MyLibComp1Targets.cmake
          MyLibComp1Targets-debug.cmake
          MyLibComp1Targets-release.cmake
      Comp2
          MyLibComp2Config.cmake
          MyLibComp2Targets.cmake
          MyLibComp2Targets-debug.cmake
          MyLibComp2Targets-release.cmake
      ...
```

Now when `find_package()` runs your main config script each component will take care of including the other components it depends on first.